# "Error getting object XXX from bucket YYY" mientras que XXX existe dentro de una carpeta del bucket

Tags: python, aws, lambda, amazon-s3

Quiero hacer una funcion Amazon lambda para hacer operaciones en un csv (`raw-survey-data.csv.gz`) de una carpeta `/processed` en un bucket Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) (`ifrac-data`) cada vez que lo necesito o que esta modificado. Dado que soy principiante con AWS empecé siguiendo [este tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) que configura un trigger para Amazon S3. El activador invoca su función cada vez que añade un objeto a su bucket de Amazon S3.

He seguido todos los pasos:

- <strike>Crear un bucket y cargar un objeto de muestra</strike> Utilicé el bucket existente
- Crear la funcion lambda en el region del bucket

Al crear la funcion obtenia un mensaje la funcion fue cread pero no fue possible de crear el trigger. Entonces lo hice a la mano. Luego he creado el test event adaptandolo pero no obtengo un resultado de éxito:

```
Test Event Name
mys3testevent

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 17, in lambda_handler\n    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 3d3d773b-d807-4c1b-8bb9-f77ec082914c Version: $LATEST
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
Error getting object raw-survey-data.csv.gz from bucket ifrac-data. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 17, in lambda_handler
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
END RequestId: 3d3d773b-d807-4c1b-8bb9-f77ec082914c
REPORT RequestId: 3d3d773b-d807-4c1b-8bb9-f77ec082914c  Duration: 249.62 ms Billed Duration: 250 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 72 MB  Init Duration: 405.08 ms

Request ID
3d3d773b-d807-4c1b-8bb9-f77ec082914c
```

No lo entiendo. Me aseguré de que existen y `ifrac-data` está en la misma región que esta función.

¿Esto se debe a que raw-survey-data.csv.gz está en una carpeta dentro de Bucket ifrac-data?
¿Debo poner el nombre del cubo en su lugar? Pero entonces, ¿cómo se comprueba sólo los posibles cambios en el archivo?

## Es a causa de que no tengo los permisos ?

Pero la funcion lambda es relacionada con `my-s3-function-role`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y `my-s3-function-role` tiene read access sobre read

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido en JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sin embargo he descubrido un simulador de que es posible con las policies y me contesta que no es posible acceder a S3 con este role

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estás mostrando información importante sobre el rol. Vale, si, tiene acceso de lectura a S3, pero no se ven las condiciones (que podrían estar mal puestas y dar como resultado una denegación de acceso)

Comment: Bien, ¿y dónde puedo encontrar esta información? @eferion

Comment: Haz click sobre el servicio "S3" en el rol. Ese enlace te desplegará los permisos asociados al servicio S3. Ahí deberías tener el permiso "GetObject". Si no lo tienes lo añades y lo configuras. Si lo tienes, haz click sobre el mismo y saca una captura de la configuración de ese permiso (tacha aquella información que creas que puede ser sensible)

Comment: No he entendido tu último comentario, lo siento

Comment: Decía que he clicado en "GetObject" y está bastante vacío @eferion . ¿Debería haber visto al menos algunos nombres de Bucket?

Comment: Pues a ver, depende. Si el json tiene algo tal que `"Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "s3:GetObject" ], "Resource": "*"` entonces debería funcionarte... salvo que tengas por ahí alguna otra política que esté prohibiendo, de forma explícita, el acceso al recurso

Comment: Haz clic sobre el botón `{ } JSON` y muestra el contenido la política, según yo no es suficiente con indicar el recurso, sino que debes decirle que el permiso será sobre todo lo que se encuentre dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Lee con tranquilidad el mensaje de error. Te dice hasta en cuatro ocasiones qué es lo que está pasando.

Las dos primeras se encuentran en esta línea aquí:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Y las dos siguientes un poco más abajo:

> [ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Motivo: **AccessDenied**. Tu Lambda no tiene permisos para acceder al recurso almacenado en S3.

Tienes que editar el rol de la Lambda para permitirle el acceso

Comment: Muchas gracias eferion para tu respuesta. Sin embargo he dado a la funcion el role `my-s3-function-role` que tiene los permisos para leer al recurso almacenado en S3.